# Use GTFS Schedule Viewer In Visual C#

Tags: c#, schedule, timetable, gtfs

I have used Google's GTFS Schedule Viewer to visualize my Google Transit data. This has worked for me. However, I want to know how to display my schedule viewer in my Visual C# application. It seems you must run the schedule_viewer.exe file in order to view the website. How do I view the schedule? I want to be able to view it in a WebBrowser control. This is the schedule viewer website: https://support.google.com/transitpartners/answer/1095563?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The schedule viewer isn't really designed for what you have in mind.  It's mostly just a diagnostic utility designed to be run as a stand-alone app.  It's also written in Python, which wouldn't integrate well with C#.

That said, the app is just spinning up a simple web server to generate the schedule viewer pages, so you could theoretically run the app in a server somewhere and have your app embed the remote webpages in a WebBrowser control.  Seems a bit hacky but crazier things have been tried.

If you are interested in web-based display of transit data, you might also consider tools like  the OneBusAway application suite (https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway/wiki)